# Building a cedar flower bed

Tags: cedar

I'm planning on building a cedar planter box in front of my house. It will be about 3 feet X 20 feet long (1 foot deep). I plan on using 4x4 posts then screw on some cedar fence boards.

My question is, do I need to oil or line the inside of the flower bed to protect the cedar? I've never built a flower bed before, nor have I ever used cedar.

Comment: Not really an answer - but I did not protect the cedar in my raised bed and am not really concerned about accelerated rotting, though I haven’t had it long enough to be sure if my decision was good or not.